# Creating reminders using HTML widgets in iBooks Author

Tags: ios, ibooks

I'm writing a book in iBooks Author. I want to be able to tap on a widget and create reminders in the Reminders app, preferably without using another app as a middleman. Any ideas how I might be able to accomplish this?

Edit: I've found an undocumented URL scheme called x-apple-reminder://, but I can't find any information on arguments I can pass to it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the reminders app has an open API that can be accessed through the web (read: HTML). You will have to have a companion app that takes a custom URL and creates a reminder.

Comment: I've found an undocumented URL scheme called x-apple-reminder://, but I can't find any information on arguments I can pass to it. Thoughts?

Comment: Those url schemes were removed in iOS 5.1